# How to fix "URL is Incomplete" error at Facebook Instant Articles

Tags: facebook, facebook-instant-articles

When I try to submit my HTML code for Facebook's new Instant Articles, I get the error below. This is the only error I get and it is displayed at the bottom of the pasted code.

> URL is Incomplete: The URL used for this media element is missing
>   information. We have automatically filled in information for you.
>   Please check that the URL is now correct and complete.

Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently had the same problem. 
You need the "full" address to (for example) an image.

img src="/path/to/img/" - wont work

img src="http://mydomain.de/path/to/img/" - worked in my example

Comment: Funny thing is that it says it filled automatically that url for me but I checked actually it didn't. That's why I confused.

Comment: I was first confused too, but my past experience with facebook taught me that you can never trust anything you see ;)